# How to make Entity View show Entity's custom dynamic label as page title (D8)

Tags: 8, entities

My custom content Entity overrides label() to provide a dynamically generated, human-readable label like:

```
public function label() {
  return $this->displayName();
}
```

Unfortunately, that label does not get used by the EntityViewController. In my module.routing.yml file I have:

```
entity.veranstaltung.canonical:
  path: '/admin/veranstaltung/{veranstaltung}'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: 'veranstaltung'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'veranstaltung.view'
```

I can now view my "veranstaltung" entities, but the page title is blank and the breadcrumb just shows the entity's id instead of its label.

Looking in EntityViewController::buildTitle() I can now see why this is the case:

```
$label_field = $entity->getEntityType()->getKey('label');
if (isset($page[$label_field])) {
  $page['#title'] = $this->renderer->render($page[$label_field]);
}
```

I don't have a label key, as I want the labels to be dynamically generated.

Any suggestions how to best deal with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to the `NodeViewController`, you can write you own `VeranstaltungViewController` extending `EntityViewController`, and implement a title function. In your route can then set `_title_callback` to use this function (see `NodeRouteProvider` as reference).

Comment: Sounds plausible. I guess, if I override `EntityViewController::buildTitle()`, I won't need the `_title_callback`?

Comment: That is how I understood the titles: The page title is generated by buildTitle(), and the breadcrumbs by either _title or _title_callback

Comment: So, just to get an understanding of this: Why doesn't `EntityViewController` use `EntityInterface::label()` to generate page titles and bread crumbs?

Comment: EntityViewController contains a comment explaining the reason:
`// If the entity's label is rendered using a field formatter, set the
// rendered title field formatter as the page title instead of the default
// plain text title. This allows attributes set on the field to propagate
// correctly (e.g. RDFa, in-place editing).`
It does not use the string of the label, but renders it with its field formatter.